# Длинные идентификаторы пользователей VK

Tags: вконтакте, числа, byte

Еще давно я наблюдал во ВКонтакте длинные идентификаторы пользователей, например:
Ссылка `vk.com/id1` будет эквивалентом `vk.com/id4294967297`.

Я разобрался лишь в том, что это число `4294967296` это `2^32` степени, еще тот факт, что если брать `2^32` (к примеру) и прибавить к нему свой идентификатор страницы, то мы получаем тот самый длинный ID.

PS. Проверял так же `2^33` и выше по такому же принципу, все так же получается длинные идентификаторы.

Вопрос: откуда берутся такие числа? И как их можно получить не ручным перебором?

Comment: Банальное переполнение 32-битного int

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, стоит прочитать про это, а как же находить такие числа, что-то я не совсем понимаю?

Comment: Какие "такие" и зачем их находить?

Comment: @MBo, просто интересно)

Comment: id + 2^(32+k) ?

Comment: @MBo, а что за параметр `k`?

Comment: любое неотрицательное целое число

Comment: @MBo, если хотите можете расписать полным ответом, приму, спасибо большое)

Comment: Написал более общее решение.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Не в первый раз замечаю, что вы в очередях проверок ставите "выглядит нормально" на ответах, которые не являются ответами, а являются комментариями. Пожалуйста, делайте проверки более качественно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Требуется найти числа, которые по модулю `2^32` равны заданному `ID`.

В общем виде это выглядят так:

```
ID + (k * 2^32)
```

Подробнее:

- `k` - неотрицательное целое число `(0, 1, 2, 3, ...)`
- `ID` - идентификатор пользователя VK